# prevent Just-In-Time debugger window from showing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I have an application that is a mix of WindowsForms and WPF.

In the Main method I have:

```
AppDomain.Currentdomain.UnhandledException += 
new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

In the CurrentDomain_UnhandledException method I display a dialog box with "continue" and "quit" buttons. When user clicks "quit" button I close the dialog box and call Application.Exit(new CancelEventArgs(true)). When user clicks "continue" button I just close the dialog box.

Now, when one of the Wpf Form is open and exception occurs, then this dialog box appears either I click "continue" or "quit" button, I get this Just-In-Time debugger window and application closes in both cases. How to prevent this ?

Comment: Well, you could start your project without the debugger (default: Ctrl + F5), but judging by your description, I'd say you'll see a "Program has crashed" window instead.

Comment: that is exactly what I am doing and this happens then only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Application.DispatcherUnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx)

We use it like this:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException +=
    OnWpfUnhandledException;
```

And, you have to set the `e.Handled = true`

Comment: Justin, Why AppDomain.Currentdomain.UnhandledException won't get invoked at the end of the day in wpf ?

Comment: It does get called. However, the application is already dead at that point

Comment: When you say "dead", do you mean to say that the application wont continue further ?

In my application the handler method displays a dialog box which simply has the reporting option and user has option to continue or quit. In case of continue, the application keeps on running.

Comment: Read the documentation at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is just not how the AppDomain.UnhandledException event works.  When it is raised, your program is already dead and cannot continue anymore.  Calling Application.Exit() will not have the intended effect.  Nor should you ever call it, it is *way* too dangerous since it is quite liable to cause yet another crash.

It is over when your event handler runs, your program cannot continue running.  Do the minimum amount possible, just logging the exception or displaying a message box.  You will want to preserve e.UnhandledException.ToString() since it gives the crash reason and a stack trace, very valuable to diagnose the cause of the crash.

Returning from your event handler causes the normal unhandled exception handling to occur, the JIT debugger on your dev machine, the Windows Error Reporting dialog on your user's machine.  You'll need to instead call Environment.Exit() so your program terminates.